# What happens when a variable is assigned to zero in an `if` condition?

Tags: c

It would be helpful if anybody can explain this.

```
int main()
{
 int a=0;
 if(a=0)
       printf("a is zero\t");
 else
       printf("a is not zero\t");
 printf("Value of a is %d\n",a);
 return 0;
}
```

output of this is

```
a is not zero   Value of a is 0
```

Comment: A line of your code is in error:  `if(a=0)` should be `if(a==0)`.

Comment: You used the assignment operator not the comparison operator ==

Comment: You have to clarify what you want explained. The code functionality is straightforward. And, judging by the title of your question, you seem to understand already that the `a=0` under `if` is an assignment, not a comparison. What's the problem then?

Comment: The title says "zero is assigned again" so presumably the second assignment is intentional. But I'm voting to close for general lack of clarity and research.

Comment: @JimBalter, I agree with you. Lack of clarity and research.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, i know the difference between them. m reassigning a to 0.

Comment: @AndreyT The problem is that the text of the messages is backwards ... it would be right if they were inverted.

Comment: In any real program, if someone wrote that it would most likely be an error, not intentional.

Comment: @Barmar Unless there was a comment that said `// I explicitly intend assignment here` ... which is pretty close to the title of this question.

Comment: @Ani: Er... Value of zero if treated as `false` in logical context (under `if`, for example). For this reason `else` branch of your `if` is taken. Why you wrote `"a is not zero"` in that branch is really a question to you. It is you, who for some strange reason arranged these messages "backwards". That's all there is to it.

Comment: not only it is obvious from the title that an assignment is what is wanted, but STLDeveloper didn't suggest the standard way of avoiding such a possible error when comparison is wanted: if(0==a) .

Comment: Since the assignment in the if-expression is intentional, you could fix your code by doing `if((a=0) == 0)`

Comment: "fixing" the code is not relevant here ... it's a request for an explanation of why the code--as written--behaves as it does.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**The result of the assignment is the value of the expression**.

Therefore:

```
if (a = 0)
```

is the same as:

```
if (0)
```

which is the same as:

```
if (false)
```

which will force the `else` path.

Answer (score 8):

```
if(a=0)
       printf("a is zero\t");
 else
       printf("a is not zero\t");
```

These messages are precisely backwards. The statement after the `if` is executed if the condition *isn't* 0, and the statement after the else is executed if the condition *is* 0, so this should be

```
if(a=0)
       printf("a is not zero\t");
 else
       printf("a is zero\t");
```

Or, equivalently but more clearly,

```
a = 0;
if(a)
       printf("a is not zero\t");
 else
       printf("a is zero\t");
```

Which, together with

```
printf("Value of a is %d\n",a);
```

would print

```
a is zero   Value of a is 0
```

as expected.

Comment: @PHIfounder I know, it's strange how many folks at SO -- programmers -- are inattentive to details. Thanks for the upvote. I think I would have gotten more if I had dashed something off instead of taking the time to get it right ... I was still writing when the accepted answer was posted.

Answer (score 1):

If () function accepts true or false value as an argument.

So whatever you put inside the bracket has no significance to if() function but of the fact what value it has.

'0' in any case is considered as false value, so when you pass 0 as an argument like:

```
if(0)
{
  ---statments---
}
```

The statement part of will not get executed, and the system will directly jump to else part.

In the case you mentioned you assigned 0 to your variable and passed it as an argument to if().
Note that if() only accepts 0 or non 0 value. So, it doesn't matter what assignment you made. if() will recieve the value of your variable 'a' as an argument and act accordingly.

In this case, since the value of a is 0, the if part will not get executed and the system will jump to else.

Answer (score 0):

`if(a=0)` is assignement of `0` in variable `a`. if you want to compare `a` against zero you need to write like below
`if(a==0)`

your condition is simple assignment which is making `a` as zero so condition getting false and you are getting prints from `else` part.

Comment: The OP doesn't want ==. The OP has made extremely clear that assignment is intended.

Comment: @JimBalter ya i know that,That is why i have given reason behind failing of condition and why prints from else part.I suggested comparison also just to be on safe side.